# VB is not following the relational operators correctly

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Dim Choice As String
Dim FinalChoice As Integer

Console.Writeline("Insert the number 1 or 2")
Choice = Console.Readline

    'Verification
    Do
        'Invalid
        If Choice <> "1" Or Choice <> "2" Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input")
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            Choice = Console.ReadLine

            'Valid
        Else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("Valid")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            FinalChoice = Choice
        End If
    Loop Until FinalChoice = 1 Or FinalChoice = 2
```

[Picture of Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR28X.jpg)

As you can see, the code is not doing as I intend.

Please can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want an `And` in your if-statement logic, not an `Or`.

Comment: Using negative logic is always harder to follow - I would suggest that you use `If Choice = "1" Or Choice = "2" Then` and switch the rest of your validation code around acordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution corrected using the correct operator.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Insert the number 1 or 2")
    Choice = Console.ReadLine

    'Verification
    Do
        'Invalid
        If Choice <> "1" AndAlso Choice <> "2" Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input")
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            Choice = Console.ReadLine

            'Valid
        Else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("Valid")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            FinalChoice = Integer.Parse(Choice)
        End If
    Loop Until FinalChoice = 1 Or FinalChoice = 2
```

Note the use of the short-circuited version of And, AndAlso.  Also the assignment to FinalChoice was fixed.

**An alternative**

```
    'Verification
    Do
        If Integer.TryParse(Choice, FinalChoice) AndAlso
            (FinalChoice = 1 OrElse FinalChoice = 2) Then
            'valid

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("Valid")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Else
            'invalid
            FinalChoice = 0
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input")
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            Choice = Console.ReadLine
        End If
    Loop While FinalChoice = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `OR` operator, the entire compound condition is true if *either* subcondition is true. Thus, if `CHOICE = "1"`, then the subcondition `CHOICE <> "2"` is true, and therefore the entire condition is true.

When you want to allow only two possible choices, then you want to fall into the invalid case if both subcondition 1 ***and*** subcondition 2 are invalid - if either is *valid*, you need to process as though your selection is valid.

Therefore, your condition should be `IF CHOICE <> "1" AND CHOICE <> "2"`.

Answer (score 1):

I am suppose you want your program to loop until the user enters a `1` or `2`.

The line `If Choice <> "1" Or Choice <> "2" Then` translates as if the choice is not 1 or the choice is not 2, then the input is invalid.

Now, if you enter `1`, which is meets the condition `Choice <> "2"` therefore it is invalid. The same goes for when the user enters `2` and Choice <> "1"

You should change the `Or` in the middle to an `And` and I think you will see your desired results.